# Is there an efficient way of treating rendered elements inside a render loop, without using globals?

Tags: javascript, arrays, three.js, rendering

I am using `JavaScript`'s `Three.js`, and I came to a point where I have an array of complicated elements* that I wish to render only some of those each render iteration.

Up until now I was using a global array for this purpose, but I think it may not be very efficient, using such a "big" variable as global therefore I am looking for another way of doing so.

I have only came to the thought of calling `render(myArray)` each iteration, but I do not want to pass this big array each iteration as well...

*My basic "complicated" array elements are created by the same `constructor`, which contains ~10 properties (`scalars` and `mesh`es) and ~10 methods.
There's ~200 elements in this array.

Needless to say that I am very new to `JS` and `Three.js`, therefore I may ask a wrong question and will be glad to receive a correction if needed. Thanks.

Comment: First off how is your "complicated" array generated, via AJAX?

Comment: You seem to think that you 'pass' the big array by value, it's not the case : a Javascript Array is an Object / a pointer / a reference or if you like an 'arrow' pointing to some part of the memory. Same goes for the array items : they are references to a part of the memory where data is actually stored. calling `render(myArray)` only send the 64 bits address of the array, then each  `myArray[i]` is the 64 bit address of some object.

Comment: @GameAlchemist - Yep, that's what I thought, just wanted to make sure that it works the same in JS as in other languages.
But is it the way people implement this thing? Or is there a more "elegant" way?

Comment: I'm not sure i understand your question about elegance. But i saw no issues in the description you made of your project. If your code is going to be 10000+ lines and might use a lot of vars/functions/classes, then it's time to use an object as namespace. For a small project you do on your own, even quite a few globals is perfect.

Comment: @GameAlchemist - Thanks. I am not familiar with the "using an object as namespace", so I would read (http://addyosmani.com/blog/essential-js-namespacing/) and see if it fits for my needs

Comment: Well, you didn't read me well enough : since you are 'very new' to JS and your project seems not that big, forget about nameSpacing for the moment, code, enjoy the fun aspects of JS and keep cool when your app completely breaks because of some of its foolish features :-)